# Trying to get parent attribute value within a for-each loop

Tags: xslt

I cobbled together a routine that would produce a list of filter attribute values, based on certain attribute values within a given element. The function is this:

```
<xsl:template name="have_arch_attrib">

    <!-- We only add a filter attribute IF there is a arch, condition or security attribute-->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=".[@arch] | .[@condition] | .[@security]">
            <xsl:attribute name="filter">
                <xsl:for-each select="@arch | @condition | @security ">

                    <!-- Need to check and convert semis to commas-->
                    <xsl:variable name="temp_string" select="."/>
                    <xsl:variable name="rep_string">
                        <xsl:value-of select="replace($temp_string, ';', ',')"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$rep_string"/>


                    <!--<xsl:value-of select="." />-->
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

For certain elements, however, i needed to check the attributes of the parent of that element. So i rewrote the above like this:

```
<xsl:template name="parent_has_arch_attrib">

    <!-- We only add a filter attribute IF there is a arch, condition or security attribute-->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="..[@arch] | ..[@condition] | ..[@security]">
            <xsl:attribute name="filter">
                <xsl:for-each select="..[@arch] | ..[@condition] | ..[@security] ">

                    <!-- Need to check and convert semis to commas-->
                    <xsl:variable name="temp_string" select="."/>
                    <xsl:variable name="rep_string">
                        <xsl:value-of select="replace($temp_string, ';', ',')"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$rep_string"/>


                    <!--<xsl:value-of select="." />-->
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I am getting into this routine, but nothing is coming out. I think the problem is when i assign temp_string via select=".". This is getting the current element, i believe. If i try select=".." that will give me all attributes values, not just the current one being processed by the for-each loop. Can i do something like this in the for-each loop, or do i have to brake it out?

thanks for any help!

Russ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace this line...

```
<xsl:for-each select="..[@arch] | ..[@condition] | ..[@security] ">
```

With this line instead

```
<xsl:for-each select="../@arch | ../@condition | ../@security ">
```

When you do `..[@arch] | ..[@condition] | ..[@security]` all you are doing is selecting the parent node IF one of the specified attributes exist, when really you are trying to get the attributes themselves.

As an aside, you don't really need to faff about with variables here...

```
                <xsl:variable name="temp_string" select="."/>
                <xsl:variable name="rep_string">
                    <xsl:value-of select="replace($temp_string, ';', ',')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="$rep_string"/>
```

You can just simplify this to the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., ';', ',')"/>
```

Comment: I had thought that i should be able to change the for-each statement. (That is because the initial test statement determines that we DO indeed have a parent element with the desired attributes, right?)
Also thanks for the tip on reducing the value-of statement. 

I will give these a try, but thank you very much Tim!!!!